# How to determine end of file?

Tags: c

How to determine end of file?

```
FILE* cfl;
if ((cfl=fopen(csv, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file for read.\r\n");
    exit(1);
}
while (!feof(cfl)) {
    int i = 0;
    char* buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    while ((buf[i] = fgetc(cfl)) != '\n') {
        i++;
        buf = (char*)realloc(buf, sizeof(char)*(i+1));
        printf("=%d= ", i);
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';
    printf("+%d+ ", i);
    printf("%s\r\n", buf);
   free(buf);
}

fclose(cfl);
```

Everything works correctly to the last line. Since the file ends after the last line break, the program loops in `while ((buf[i] = fgetc(cfl)) != '\n') {...}`

I could interrupt the cycle after checking whether ***"i"*** does not exceed some large value, but it will be wrong. How to correctly determine the end of the file and why *feof* does not work in this case?

Comment: Read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You don't check for endof file at all in the inner while loop.

Comment: Also, `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  You can not reliably detect EOF if you read the results of `fgetc()` into a `char`.

Comment: Not sure if it's a dupe

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but reallocating a new buffer for every single char you're reading is very inefficient. You should reallocate chunks of, say, 64 kbytes at least.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: For reading lines, 64 KB is huge. Maybe 1 KB or less would more typical, I’d expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fgetc` function returns an `int`, and the value will be `EOF` at end of file. This is the typical approach:

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(cfl)) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use this. It work fine for me.

Comment: Note that you have to use feof to know if the EOF returned by fgetc mean "end of file" or "error".